# How to remove all cookies in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I can set a cookie like this:

```
$cookieStore.put('myCookie','I am a cookie');
```

And I can remove it with

```
$cookieStore.remove('myCookie');
```

But how can I remove all cookies?

Comment: Do you have all keys of cookies?

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, obviously this may not be the best solution, but I've find a workaround:

```
angular.forEach($cookies, function (v, k) {
    $cookieStore.remove(k);
});
```

But I'ld still appreciate if there's a better solution. I'm really curious about why there isn't a built-in `$cookieStore.removeAll()` method...

Requires the *ngCookies* module to be installed.

**Edit**

With the 1.4 version, `$cookieStore` is deprecated. Instead you can use `$cookies` service. Get all cookies with `$cookies.getAll()` and remove each with `$cookies.remove('key')`.

```
var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
    $cookies.remove(k);
});
```

Comment: $cookieStore is deprecated use $cookie instead

Comment: When i  am calling above function it getting some other cookies like google and _ga ... What to do to avoid this..

Comment: The above method removes every cookie which set by your domain. Filtering those cookies is out of this question's scope. But you can simply make a list and check if the cookie key is in that list...

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on this page and you working on an old project that uses angular 1.3.x or less, you can simply use this

```
$cookies.cookieKey = undefined;
delete $cookies['cookieKey'];
```