# How to clear in AngularJs server cache and cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, .htaccess

I am Using AngularJS on my website. After updating my content and hosting it on the server, it shows the previous content only. I cleared my browser history and cookies but it still shows the old content only. I set in the .htaccess file `ExpiresByType` to a minimum, like 0 sec, 1 sec but still, the old content only shows. In Hostgator.in, I have a demo server where I uploaded the website. The new content shows. But in hostgater.com I have my official server there. I uploaded the new content and it doesn't show.

Please help me.

Comment: [Hope you can find your solution from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26608139/7393095)

Comment: You can find your solution from below link: [Clear in AngularJs server cache and cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26608139/7393095)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cache:false` in your route file and use

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache();
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
```

in controller.js file I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: $scope.clear= function () {
   $ionicHistory.clearCache();
   $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
   $timeout(function () {
      }, 200)
  }

 })
use this function in your controllers.js