# Angularjs how to delete all cookies?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I am using cookies in my application. On logout i want to remove all the cookies i set. I am using $cookieStore to set cookie value. Is there any way to delete all cookies? I have used below function.

```
 $scope.logout=function()
    {
        debugger;
        angular.forEach($cookies, function (v, k) {
            $cookieStore.remove(k);
        });
    }
```

I am not sure what is $cookies in the above code? When i use above code i have below error also. $cookies is not defined. May i know is there any way to delete all cookies in one shot instead of removing one by one? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all cookies in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607856/how-to-remove-all-cookies-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hi papakias. thank you for you reference. May i know what is $cookies in the above piece of code or from the link you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cookies` is angular define service. so you need to inject this to the controller in order to use it. Also `$cookieStore` is deprecated since angular 1.4. So use `$cookies.remove(k)` instead of  `$cookieStore.remove(k);`.

```
angular.forEach($cookies, function (v, k) {
   $cookies.remove(k);
 });
```